# Promise.resolve().then not working in jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-promise

I'm trying to setup a test which involves promises. Here is my example code:

```
var promise;

beforeEach(inject(function ($q) {
    promise = $q.resolve();
}));

it('should resolve', function (done) {
    promise.then(function () {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
        done();
    });
});
```

For some reason, when I run this, I get a TIMEOUT

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Why doesn't the promise execute the callback given to `then` ?

Cheers

Comment: It's not necessary to use done method with promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call scope/rootScope $digest method to resolve promises.
So it should be:

```
var result = false;
promise.then(function() { result = true;});
$rootScope.$digest();
expect(result).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: shouldn't you actually call $digest?

Comment: If anything $rootScope.$digest(). Probably surrounded by try/catch. Doesn't work for me either, though.